# Proper way to use @Transactional on a service

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a service, which uses multiple DAOs to do a unit of work like following. The DAOs fetch the data/save by creating a session and commit. In that case, why do  i need to have transactional on the service when the dao is managing the session by itself? If something goes wrong in the second DAO, the data in the first DAO is already commited, how do I get around this situation?

```
@Transactional
public boolean testService(SomeObject obj){

     userDao.save(obj.getUser()); // this dao gets the session from sessino factory and commits there itself.
     addressDao.save(obj.getAddress()); // something fails here, and the above line has already commited the data, so the data is not Atomic.

     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you don't put `@Transactional` in your DAO layer but in your service layer.
So I suggest you remove `@Transactional` from you DAOs and keep the one in your service.

In that case, if something goes wrong in any of your DAO everything will be rollback.

But It's up to you where you want the transaction to start and to finish.

Comment: So, are yu saying that a single transaction can span across multiple sessions?

Comment: I'm assuming that userDao and addressDao use the same session. If not, is there a reason why? (because usually we use the same session for all DAOs)

Comment: I'm looking to change how my system is designed, if you could explain how you share the session between the DAOs, it will help me. Thanks

Comment: Here is a project who use hibernate with spring and transaction. You can have a look at the DAOs/Entity and the spring/hibernate config file. https://github.com/theewook/war-sec-clustr

Comment: Great! nice way to start for me. one more question, I see that you used semaphore, seems to me like you are trying get a lock on the table rows? or is it for some other purpose?

Comment: Also, i've been reading, hibernate somehow returns you the same session when you call session.getcurrentSession() within a transaction.

Comment: You're right. It's not exactly the scope of your question but FYI, my application has to be deployed on multiple instances. So, to be sure that only one instance can update the table at a time, I created a Semaphore class to get a lock/release locks on a table.

Comment: but, isn't it session.lock() meant for the same purpose?

Comment: @Zeus Yes! you are right. session.lock does it too. So why I didn't use session.lock instead? That's a good question. But unfortunately, I can't answer this question. I don't know exactly what's behind session.lock and how it behaves in a clustered environment. Perhaps this point deserve its own question?